# How to update different colors to different areas in a Map component of React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a Texas statemap with the list of counties. And while hovering over each area, the area name is displayed. But all the counties in the map are showing with same color.
I need to update each color to different area in a way that neighbouring counties should not be displayed with same color.

how to do that?

```
type MapProps = {
  state: string
  stateId: string
  mapColor?: string
  mapHoverColor?: string
}

export function MapLink(props: MapProps) {
  const option = {
    textStyle: {
      fontFamily: '"Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif',
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      formatter: (params: any) => {
        const wda = wdaCounties.wdas.filter((item) => item.counties.includes(params.name))
        const counties = wda[0].wda
        return counties
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Selected',
        type: 'map',
        map: 'Texas',
        nameProperty: 'NAME',
        selectedMode: 'multiple',
        right: '10px',
        label: {
          show: false,
        },
  
        emphasis: {
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            areaColor: props.mapHoverColor||'#EADDCA',
          },
        },
        itemStyle: {
          areaColor: props.mapColor||'#5f8f2c',
        },
        select: {
          label: {
            show: false,
          },
          itemStyle: {
            areaColor: props.mapHoverColor||'#EADDCA',
          },
        },
        data: [],
      },
    ],
  }
  const mapRef = useRef<EChartsInstance | null>(null)
  const [mapOptions] = useState({
    ...option,
    series: [
      {
        ...option.series[0],
        map: props.state,
      },
    ],
  })

  const texasCountyData = {
    type: usCountyDta.type,
    features: usCountyDta.features.filter((feature) => feature.properties.STATE === props.stateId),
  }



  // @ts-ignore
  echarts.registerMap(props.state, texasCountyData)

  const updateMap = (map: EChartsInstance, selection: string[]) => {
    try {
      map.dispatchAction({
        type: EVENT_UNSELECT,
        name: texasCountyData.features.map((feature) => feature.properties.NAME),
      })

      map.dispatchAction({
        type: EVENT_SELECT,
        name: selection,
      })
    } catch { }
  }
  if (mapRef.current) {
    let mapInstance = mapRef.current.getEchartsInstance()

    mapInstance.on(EVENT_CLICK, (params: any) => {
      const wda = wdaCounties.wdas.filter((item) => item.counties.includes(params.name))
      const counties = wda[0].counties
      const url = wda[0].url
      window.open(url, "_self")
    })
    mapInstance.on('mouseover', (params: any) => {
      const wda = wdaCounties.wdas.filter((item) => item.counties.includes(params.name))
      const counties = wda[0].counties
      updateMap(mapInstance, counties)
    })

    mapInstance.on('mouseout', () => {
    
      updateMap(mapInstance, [])
    })

   
  }

  return (
    <>

      <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        ......
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful